# What is the most efficient way to perform a t.test from tidy data in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a dataset that was poorly formatted and I'm trying to get it into a tidy format for statistical testing and data visualization. I'm hoping someone can provide some insight on whether I have the data in the correct tidy format and what the simplest way to perform multiple t.tests.

Here is some sample data similar to my untidied format:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame("subject_id" = 1:10, "age" = 21:30, "weight" = 150:159, "height" = 65:74,
                   "x_c1_avg" = c(1:9, NA), "y_c1_avg" = runif(10),"z_c1_avg" = c(9:1, NA),
                   "x_c2e1_avg" = c(1:9, NA), "y_c2e1_avg" = runif(10), "z_c2e1_avg" = runif(10),
                   "x_c2e2_avg" = runif(10), "y_c2e2_avg" = runif(10), "z_c2e2_avg" = runif(10))

glimpse(data)
```

The tibble contains demographic information and then three measures, collected at different conditions with some of the measures being performed by two examiners (e.g. x_c1_avg is the average for measure x collected at condition 1 (a certain leg position) and y_c2e1_avg is the average for measure y collected by examiner 1 at condition 2.

**So my first question, am I correct that the output of the code below would be considered tidy?** Measure, condition and examiner are each in their own columns with the values in another column.

```
data2 <- data %>%
  gather(key = "condition", value = "value", -c(subject_id:height)) %>%
  separate(condition, into = c("measure", "condition"), sep = "_", extra = "drop") %>%
  separate(condition, into = c("condition", "examiner"), sep = 2, fill = "right")
```

**My second question, what is the most efficient way to perform a paired t.test on this data or is there a way to do this without creating new vectors for each variable?**  There are 12 conditions in total but I'll only be performing t.tests for six comparisons. I'd be comparing measure x at c1 to measure x at c2 for each subject or measure y by examiner 1 at condition 2 to measure y by examiner 2 at condition 2 and so on. My current code is a:

```
x_c1 <- data2 %>%
  filter(measure == "x", condition == "c1") %>%
  select(value)
x_c2_e2 <- data2 %>%
  filter(measure == "x", condition == "c2", examiner == "e2") %>%
  select(value)

t.test(x_c1$value, x_c2_e2$value, paired = TRUE)
```

However, this seems much more complicated than it needs to be and feels like I'm reversing the work I did to get it in tidy format. It would have been much easier to run this from the start:

```
t.test(data$x_c1_avg, data$x_c2e2_avg, paired = TRUE)
```

Comment: It's quite new, but maybe check out [infer](http://infer.netlify.com/reference/t_test.html)

Comment: So my understanding is that you want to run a paired t-test on every combination of `measure`, `condition` and `examiner`? That's a lot of t-tests. Maybe explain what your logic is for deciding the combinations instead of "I have many more conditions and many comparisons"?

Comment: Sure, good question. I'm not planning on running t.tests between every single possible combination of conditions. I have 12 conditions total. There are 6 comparisons of interest with t.-tests. For the rest, I will be using ANOVA. I guess a better description of my question would be, "Is the method I used in the example the most efficient or is there a better way to perform this test without creating new vectors for each variable?" I'll update the original.

Comment: @alistaire infer looks awesome, thanks for sharing. I've gotten very comfortable with the tidy grammar from the datacamp courses and have been frustrated that many of the statistical test don't play nicely with it.